# pushing object to array attribute when updating a document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using mongoose as a schema & persistence layer.

When adding an item to an array-attribute in my existing document, it would fail: err would equal `null`, raw would equal `{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`.

Any idea why this happens?

**update code**

```
 let concreteAnswer = {
  questionId: 1,
  answer: {
    rating: 34
  }
};

Participation.update(
  {
    _id: 'some-unique-id',
    'answers.$.instrumentName': 'some-instrument-name' // instrumentName is unique within the answers array
  },
  {
    $push: {"answers.$.concreteAnswers" : concreteAnswer}
  },
  (err, raw) => {
    console.log(`error occured! raw: ${raw}, error: ${err}`);
  }
);
```

**schema definition**

```
var ParticipationSchema = new Schema({
    answers: [{
      instrumentName: { type: String, enum: validInstruments },
      concreteAnswers: [{
        questionId: Number,
        answer: {}
      }]
    }]
    // further attributes omitted for readability
},
{
    timestamps: true
});
var Participation = mongoose.model('Participation', ParticipationSchema);
```

**document in the db**

```
{
    "_id": "some-unique-id",
    "answers": [
      {
        "instrumentName": "some-instrument-name",
        "_id": "another-unique-id",
        "concreteAnswers": []
      },
      // etc.
}
```

**2017-04-16: CHANGED UPDATE CODE ACCORDING TO @VEERAM'S COMMENTS:**

```
Participation.update(
  {
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('some-unique-id'),
    'answers.instrumentName': 'some-instrument-name'
  },
  {
    $push: {"answers.$.concreteAnswers" : concreteAnswerDto}
  },
  // ERR HANDLING AS ABOVE
}
```

I also just realized, that now the operation works (i.e. the doc would be updated in the db), but it would still execute the `console.log` within the error handling.

Comment: Try `'answers.instrumentName': 'some-instrument-name'`. Remove the $ from query.

Comment: @Veeram didn't have any effect, still the same issue & error message

Comment: It works fine for me.  Is your `_id` string or objectId ? If objectId try `_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(some-unique-id)`

Comment: @Veeram this actually seems to make a difference. When emitting `$` and applying `mongoose.Types.ObjectId('<id>')` I get a more specific error

`details: MongoError: cannot use the part (instruments of instruments.currentQuestionId) to traverse the element ({instruments: [ { name: "motivational-drivers", currentQuestionId: 0, completed: false, _id: ObjectId('58f3823119d86442fd5840de') }, { name: "cultural-fit", currentQuestionId: 0, completed: false, _id: ObjectId('58f3823119d86442fd5840dd') } ]}) { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`

Comment: Can you show the full query ? Also did you update the schema ? Please update the post with the latest. Please note you can only go one level deep with positional operator.

Comment: @Veeram I posted the modified update code. Note that it "works" now but it would still execute the error block. I need to go 1 level deep only with the current schema, right? I post a "concreteAnswer" to `answers[i].concreteAnswers`, where `i` is obviously the index of the `answers` array. Therefore `answers.$.concreteAnswers` should be correct (since it also works now)... Still confused about the error occuring.

Comment: @Veeram I just read up on the mongoose docs, my error handling code is wrong. I'll need to check for `err` to be falsy. Since `err` is `null` there is no error. Thanks and feel free to formulate a proper answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: Awesome. You are welcome. Its just troubleshooting. No need for answer here.

Comment: Cool. Thank you, appreaciate!